# AutoCompleteTextView select text on space

Tags: android

Is it possible for a `AutoCompleteTextView` to select the first item in the drop down list when a user hits the space key, instead of the user selecting one of the items from the list?

I have tried using `TextChangedListener`, `dispatchKeyEvent` and `onKeyDown`.